# Alert with Json - Pine Script

Tags: python, json, tradingview-api

i have made my Indicator in Tradingview and connect that to my Telegram bot with python.
i want to change the alert in Tradingview to json and send it via Webhock but i have a problem

```
T1 = startPrice
E1 = startPrice + diff * -0.27
E2 = startPrice + diff * -0.414
E3 = startPrice + diff * -0.618
SL = startPrice + diff * -0.786
if Short or Long
    Tmessage = '{"Ticker":"'+syminfo.ticker+'",'+
        '"Position":'+str.tostring(message)+','+
        '"Position":"'+message+'",'+
        '"Entry 1":'+str.tostring(E1)+','+
        '"Target 1":'+str.tostring(T1)+','+
        '"Entry 2":'+str.tostring(E2)+','+
        '"Target 2":'+str.tostring(E1)+','+
        '"Entry 3":'+str.tostring(E3)+','+
        '"Target 3":'+str.tostring(E2)+','+
        '"Stop Lost":'+str.tostring(SL)+
        '}'
    alert('{"Ticker":"TEST"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

Error is:
Exception Occured : argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Error is:
Exception Occured : argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First off all you didnt define the startPrice, Short, Long,diff varible. Second of all the if statement is missing a ":". Here i the working code:

```
Short = true
Long = true
startprice = 2
diff = 3
T1 = startPrice
E1 = startPrice + diff * -0.27
E2 = startPrice + diff * -0.414
E3 = startPrice + diff * -0.618
SL = startPrice + diff * -0.786
if Short or Long:
    Tmessage = '{"Ticker":"'+syminfo.ticker+'",'+
        '"Position":'+str.tostring(message)+','+
        '"Position":"'+message+'",'+
        '"Entry 1":'+str.tostring(E1)+','+
        '"Target 1":'+str.tostring(T1)+','+
        '"Entry 2":'+str.tostring(E2)+','+
        '"Target 2":'+str.tostring(E1)+','+
        '"Entry 3":'+str.tostring(E3)+','+
        '"Target 3":'+str.tostring(E2)+','+
        '"Stop Lost":'+str.tostring(SL)+
        '}'
    alert('{"Ticker":"TEST"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```